# Set 0 for some columns in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

My problem is that I want to set 0 for each missing `LAST_YARD_ROW`
assuming that each park has its  own number or rows.

The problem is on the cross join line.

```
SELECT  
    lypb.last_yard_park,
    lypb.last_yard_bay,
    lyr.last_yard_row,
    0 top_tier
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         last_yard_bay,LAST_YARD_PARK 
     FROM
         TOWERS) lypb
CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT LAST_YARD_ROW FROM TOWERS) lyr (last_yard_row)
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM TOWERS t
                WHERE t.last_yard_bay = lypb.last_yard_bay
                  AND t.LAST_YARD_PARK= lypb.LAST_YARD_PARK
                  AND t.last_yard_row = lyr.last_yard_row)

UNION

SELECT * 
FROM TOWERS
ORDER BY 
    LAST_YARD_PARK, LAST_YARD_BAY, LAST_YARD_ROW;
```

This is my output:

```
 park   Bay    Row      Tier
 A1     007    00A      01
 A1     007    00B      0
 A1     007    00C      0
 A1     007    00D      0
 A1     007    00E      05
 A2     007    00A      0
 A2     007    00B      02
 A2     007    00C      0
 A2     007    00D      0
 A2     007    00E      0
```

And the expected output is because park A2 has only `00A` `00B` `00C` rows only

```
 park   Bay    Row      Tier
 A1     007    00A      01
 A1     007    00B      0
 A1     007    00C      0
 A1     007    00D      0
 A1     007    00E      05
 A2     007    00A      0
 A2     007    00B      02
 A2     007    00C      0
```

Comment: Post some sample and expected output data.

Comment: In my experience here, phrases in a question like "The problem is..." very often indicate a potential X-Y Problem. What are you trying to do? Sample data and expectation are needed. I'm not sure if the `CROSS JOIN` is even necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add a filter after the cross join over `lyr.LAST_YARD_ROW`to make it work like this:

```
SELECT  
    lypb.last_yard_park,
    lypb.last_yard_bay,
    lyr.last_yard_row,
    0 top_tier
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
    last_yard_bay,LAST_YARD_PARK 
FROM
     TOWERS) lypb
CROSS JOIN 
     (SELECT DISTINCT LAST_YARD_ROW FROM TOWERS) lyr (last_yard_row)
WHERE 
    lyr.LAST_YARD_ROW IN 
    (select distinct LAST_YARD_ROW FROM TOWERS 
    WHERE LAST_YARD_PARK=lypb.LAST_YARD_PARK )
AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM TOWERS t
            WHERE t.last_yard_bay = lypb.last_yard_bay
              AND t.LAST_YARD_PARK= lypb.LAST_YARD_PARK
              AND t.last_yard_row = lyr.last_yard_row)

UNION

SELECT * 
FROM TOWERS
ORDER BY 
    LAST_YARD_PARK, LAST_YARD_BAY, LAST_YARD_ROW;
```